# if == True, make True for one moment while in loop

Tags: python

Could someone please help me with this?

This is all happening in a loop, so Input1 is always being called. When Input1 switches to True I would like Output1 to turn on, and then off, like a light switch, so for an ms. This on, then off I would like to only happen once while the Input1 is still being called. So later on if Input1 goes back to False and then True after that, it wont affect Output1 which has had its 'switch' - (on then off), happen once already. I hope that helps?

```
#Input1 is a boolean
on = True
off = False
if Input1 == True:
    Output1 = on
    #Only turn on for one moment
    #then turn off right away even while Input1 continues to be True
else:
    Output1 = off
```

I thought I could do something like this:

```
#Input1 is a boolean
on = True
off = False
count = 0
if Input1 == True and count == 0:
    Output1 = on
    count = 1
else:
    Output1 = off
```

Comment: Note that `if Input1 == True:` is redundant. You can simply write `if Input1:` and `Input1` is evaluated as a `bool`.

Comment: What do you mean by "only set `on` to `True` for a moment"? Is this a loop? I think you need to post more code or provide more context.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, strongly disagree, especially when speaking of dynamic languages such as Python. If I have a statement of `if Input1 == True` - I have an explicitly sure that `Input1` is a boolean variable. `if Input1` - is a hell, because if `Input1` is not a boolean (e.g. a string), `bool('') == False` but `bool('abc') == True`). Always do explicit checks.

Comment: @BasicWolf: PEP8 states explicitly *"Don't compare boolean values to True or False using =="*

Comment: @BasicWolf Good luck writing a program where you've no idea what type of object a name is bound to!

Comment: What you're asking doesn't make sense. If you want a code block to execute once (excluding it being in a loop, in which case you'd need a toggle), simply **don't** wrap it in an `if` selection control structure.

Comment: Step back from the code and tell us what you're trying to achieve, in a more general sense. You're not *'trying to just get the comparison Input1 == True statement to pass once'* - that's only an implementation detail of one of many possible implementations. What is the significance of *count*? What programming structure is all this happening inside (loop, function, class method,...)? How long should Output1 stay on, for a fixed delay in ms, or until some other event? etc.

Comment: @JakubM. Thanks for pointing to PEP8. Damn, I read that document lots of times and always missed the booleans part :(

Comment: Im sorry all, here is some more explanation - This is all happening in a loop, so Input1 is always being called. When Input1 switches to True I would like Output1 to turn on, and then off, like a light switch, so for an ms. This on, then off I would like to only happen once while the Input1 is still being called. So later on if Input1 goes back to False and then True after that, it wont affect Output1 which has had its 'switch' - (on then off), happen once already. I hope that helps? Sorry for my lack of detail in my first post.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, you want to, on the first iteration of a loop, execute a section of code which isn't activated on subsequent loops. Below follows your idea of Input1/Output1 though I'd suggest comparing `count` instead of having `Output1` (as it is redundant).

```
count = 0
Input1 = True
while True:
    if Input1:
        print("Doing Input1 stuff...")
        count = count + 1
        if count == 1: #if the count is 1 it is the FIRST iteration of the loop so we switch on!
            Output1 = True
            print("Output 1 switched ON")
    if Output1: 
        print("Out-putted")
        Output1 = False #switch if OFF, and since count will never = 1 again, this code block won't activate again.
        print("Output 2 switched OFF")
    #break the loop sometime (this is just for demonstration)
    if count == 4:
        print("I've done 4 iterations")
        break;
```

Produces

```
>>> 
Doing Input1 stuff...
Output 1 switched ON
Out-putted
Output 2 switched OFF
Doing Input1 stuff...
Doing Input1 stuff...
Doing Input1 stuff...
I've done 4 iterations
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use break statement like this:

```
on = True
off = False
if Input1 == True:
    Output1 = on
    break
else:
    Output1 = off
```

By doing this, Once Output1 will get True value, it will be remain same. It will break the statement and will not go for another iteration.

Comment: Where did you ever see that the code was in a loop?